# How to wrap all div with first link

Tags: javascript, jquery

there are more than one div in my web page and I want to wrap them with the first link inside of my div.I wrote a function for that but I guess it's not dynamically and all div has same link where is my fault ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var findAlink = $(".tab-col-2").find("a").attr("href");
   $(".tab-col-2").wrapAll('<a href="'+findAlink+'"></a>');
});
```

```css
.tab-col-2{
  width:400px;
  height:330px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.tab-col-2 img{
  width:100%;
  height:170px; 
  display:block;
}
.tab-col-2 h2,.tab-col-2 p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  
<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  
<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the div and wrap the element with the existing `a` tag by unwrapping the `img` first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // iterate over the divs
  $(".tab-col-2").each(function() {
    // get the `a` tag within the div
    var $a = $('a', this);
    // unwrap the img tag
    $('img', $a).unwrap();  
    // get all child nodes and wrap it with the cached `a` tag
    $(this).contents().wrapAll($a)
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tab-col-2").each(function() {
    var $a = $(this).find('a')
    $('img', $a).unwrap();
    $(this).contents().wrapAll($a)
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-col-2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.tab-col-2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  display: block;
}
.tab-col-2 h2,
.tab-col-2 p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="tab-col-2">
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
    </a>
    <h2>Title of the box</h2>
    <p>explain of the title</p>
    <p>73,40 US</p>
    <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
  </div>
  <!-- col-->


  <div class="tab-col-2">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
    </a>
    <h2>Title of the box</h2>
    <p>explain of the title</p>
    <p>73,40 US</p>
    <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
  </div>
  <!-- col-->


  <div class="tab-col-2">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com">
      <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
    </a>
    <h2>Title of the box</h2>
    <p>explain of the title</p>
    <p>73,40 US</p>
    <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
  </div>
  <!-- col-->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each div and then wrap it inside  tag

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $(".tab-col-2").each(function(){
    var findAlink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).wrapAll('<a href="'+findAlink+'"></a>');
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-col-2{
  width:400px;
  height:330px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.tab-col-2 img{
  width:100%;
  height:170px; 
  display:block;
}
.tab-col-2 h2,.tab-col-2 p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  
<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  
<div class="tab-col-2">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">
 <img src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<h2>Title of the box</h2>
<p>explain of the title</p>
<p>73,40 US </p>
  <a href="#">my boxes..</a>
</div><!-- col-->
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```